# How to return a non-zero exit status from a custom Flask command?

Tags: python, flask, command-line-interface

I'm trying to create a simple [custom Flask command](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/cli/#custom-commands), which may either succeed of fail. I want to set the exit status of the command accordingly. How can I do that? I've tried using `return 1` to indicate an error, but still the exit status of the command is always `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest thing to do is probably to simply call `sys.exit` from within your custom command:

```py
import sys

import click
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.cli.command("test-error-code")
def test_error_code():
    sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: What if I need to add a unit test for this command?

Comment: You would catch the SystemExit exception, like any other exception.

Comment: eg, `self.assertRaises(SystemExit, my_call, ...)` in the Python unittest framework